# Bash Menu - Return to Main Menu from SubMenu?

Tags: bash, menu, submenu

I've got a simple Bash Menu here. Everything seems to work great, except I can't figure out how to get back to the Main Menu from my SubMenu. Upon executing the script, I select "3" to go into the "SubMenu" from there, I press "3" again to go back to the "Main Menu" but instead it just keeps showing me the "SubMenu" options.

I tried replacing "break" with "./menu.sh" which is the name of my script, which does seem to work, however, I'm certain that's probably not the most ideal way to handle this issue.

```
#!/bin/bash
clear

while true
do
clear

echo "######"
echo " Menu"
echo "######"
echo ""

PS3='Select an option: '
options=("Option1" "Option2" "SubMenu" "Exit")

select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
    case $opt in
        "Option1")
            echo Option1
            read -p ""
            break
            ;;
        "Option2")
            echo Option2
            read -p ""
            break
            ;;
        "SubMenu")
            while true
            do
            clear
            echo "#########"
            echo " SubMenu"
            echo "#########"
            echo ""
            PS3='Select an option: '
            options=(
              "SubMenu Option1"
              "SubMenu Option2"
              "Main Menu"
            )
            select opt2 in "${options[@]}"
            do
              case $opt2 in
                  "SubMenu Option1")
                      echo "Sub-Menu Option1"
                      read -p ""
                      break
                      ;;
                  "SubMenu Option2")
                      echo "Sub-Menu Option2"
                      read -p ""
                      break
                      ;;
                    "Main Menu")
                      "./menu"
                      ;;
                  *) echo "invalid option";;
            esac
          done
        done
            ;;
        "Exit")
            exit
            ;;
        *) echo "invalid option"
           ;;
    esac
  done
done
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `break` will break out of `select`. To leave the submenu `while` loop, you need to `break 3` (to leave the inner `select`, the submenu `while`, and the outer `select`).

Type `help break` for more information.

A short note on your other approach, calling your script again: You should not launch a new child process with each iteration. Bash has an elegant way of "restarting" a program:

```
exec "$0"
```

This will execute the given executable (in this case `$0` – the current script) in the current process. See the [`exec()` system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exec_(system_call)) for more information or type `help exec` to read the Bash specifics.

Comment: I was hesitant to make this post as I'm one of those people who HATES asking for help. But I'm so glad that I did because not only did you solve my issue, but you also went above and beyond to give me the tip about restarting my script using exec "$0"

So Thank You very much for this excellent answer. I really appreciate it. =).

Comment: @XenonKilla I know what you mean, glad I could help.

Comment: Michael, I ran across something else I was hoping you might have a solution for. While at the Main Menu, if I type in any value that doesn't exist, I will get an "Invalid Option" prompt. But what I can't figure out is where I can modify the script so that I can change the behavior of when the user just hits "Enter" without typing a value. I want to be able to add the "exec "$0" so that it restarts the script rather than the current behavior of just reprinting the menu on top of the original menu. Any ideas?